# How to use WebClient with HTTPS proxy

Tags: kotlin, proxy, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I'm trying to configure `WebClient` to work with HTTPS proxy.

Here is my WebClient configuration:

```
    @Bean
    fun webClientWithProxy(
        builder: WebClient.Builder,
        mapper: ObjectMapper
    ): WebClient {
        val sslContext = SslContextBuilder
            .forClient()
            .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
            .build()

        val connector = ReactorClientHttpConnector(
            HttpClient.create().tcpConfiguration { tcpClient ->
                tcpClient
                    .secure { sslProvider ->
                        sslProvider.sslContext(sslContext)
                    }
                    .proxy { proxyProvider ->
                        proxyProvider.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP).address(InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort))
                    }
            }
        )
        return builder.clientConnector(connector).build()
    }
```

Here is my log:

```
2020-11-09 10:56:22.668 gpb-requestid[] gpb-traceid[] gpb-guid[] ERROR 42583 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [42f94c64-1] 500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/some/api/path"
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: failure when writing TLS control frames
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailureTransportFailure(SslHandler.java:1870)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST /some/api/path [DefaultWebClient]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler my.project.Controller#address(Map, ServerWebExchange) [DispatcherHandler]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ springfox.boot.starter.autoconfigure.SwaggerUiWebFluxConfiguration$CustomWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ my.project.new.logging.filter.RequestLoggingFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ my.project.new.logging.filter.SessionIdFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ my.project.new.logging.filter.RequestIdFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ my.project.new.logging.filter.ParamsFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ my.project.new.logging.filter.LoginFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ my.project.new.logging.filter.HeadersPreparationFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/some/api/path" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailureTransportFailure(SslHandler.java:1870)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.access$600(SslHandler.java:167)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$2.operationComplete(SslHandler.java:985)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$2.operationComplete(SslHandler.java:980)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:608)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
        at io.netty.channel.PendingWriteQueue.safeFail(PendingWriteQueue.java:279)
        at io.netty.channel.PendingWriteQueue.removeAndFailAll(PendingWriteQueue.java:177)
        at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.failPendingWrites(ProxyHandler.java:435)
        at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.failPendingWritesAndClose(ProxyHandler.java:352)
        at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.setConnectFailure(ProxyHandler.java:347)
        at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.channelInactive(ProxyHandler.java:234)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:418)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:389)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:354)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.channelInactive(HttpClientCodec.java:311)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:221)
        at io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler$HttpClientCodecWrapper.channelInactive(HttpProxyHandler.java:267)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:819)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:497)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyConnectException: http, none, some.https.proxy.com/10.0.0.1:8080 => host.api.com:443, disconnected
    at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.channelInactive(ProxyHandler.java:234)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:418)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:389)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:354)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.channelInactive(HttpClientCodec.java:311)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:221)
    at io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler$HttpClientCodecWrapper.channelInactive(HttpProxyHandler.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:819)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-11-09 10:56:22.679 gpb-requestid[] gpb-traceid[] gpb-guid[]  WARN 42583 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id: 0xefaa96ea, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:52445 ! R:some.https.proxy.com/10.0.0.1:8080] The connection observed an error
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: failure when writing TLS control frames
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailureTransportFailure(SslHandler.java:1870)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST /some/api/path [DefaultWebClient]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler my.project.Controller#address(Map, ServerWebExchange) [DispatcherHandler]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ springfox.boot.starter.autoconfigure.SwaggerUiWebFluxConfiguration$CustomWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ my.project.new.logging.filter.RequestLoggingFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ my.project.new.logging.filter.SessionIdFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ my.project.new.logging.filter.RequestIdFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ my.project.new.logging.filter.ParamsFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ my.project.new.logging.filter.LoginFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ my.project.new.logging.filter.HeadersPreparationFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/some/api/path" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailureTransportFailure(SslHandler.java:1870)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.access$600(SslHandler.java:167)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$2.operationComplete(SslHandler.java:985)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$2.operationComplete(SslHandler.java:980)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:608)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
        at io.netty.channel.PendingWriteQueue.safeFail(PendingWriteQueue.java:279)
        at io.netty.channel.PendingWriteQueue.removeAndFailAll(PendingWriteQueue.java:177)
        at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.failPendingWrites(ProxyHandler.java:435)
        at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.failPendingWritesAndClose(ProxyHandler.java:352)
        at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.setConnectFailure(ProxyHandler.java:347)
        at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.channelInactive(ProxyHandler.java:234)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:418)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:389)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:354)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.channelInactive(HttpClientCodec.java:311)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:221)
        at io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler$HttpClientCodecWrapper.channelInactive(HttpProxyHandler.java:267)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:819)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:497)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyConnectException: http, none, some.https.proxy.com/10.0.0.1:8080 => host.api.com:443, disconnected
    at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.channelInactive(ProxyHandler.java:234)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:418)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:389)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:354)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.channelInactive(HttpClientCodec.java:311)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:221)
    at io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler$HttpClientCodecWrapper.channelInactive(HttpProxyHandler.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:819)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-11-09 10:56:22.684 gpb-requestid[] gpb-traceid[] gpb-guid[]  WARN 42583 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [id: 0xefaa96ea, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:52445 ! R:some.https.proxy.com/10.0.0.1:8080] The connection observed an error
io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyConnectException: http, none, some.https.proxy.com/10.0.0.1:8080 => host.api.com:443, disconnected
    at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.channelInactive(ProxyHandler.java:234)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:418)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:389)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:354)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.channelInactive(HttpClientCodec.java:311)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:221)
    at io.netty.handler.proxy.HttpProxyHandler$HttpClientCodecWrapper.channelInactive(HttpProxyHandler.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:819)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I think the problem occurs because of this string:

```
proxyProvider.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP).address(InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort))
```

`ProxyProvider.Proxy` doesn't have HTTPS, and I don't know how to ask WebClient to use it.

I checked the proxy with `curl`. It works when I use `--proxy https:\\...`, and request fails when I send it with `--proxy http:\\...`.

With `restTemplate` I can set `scheme` like this:

```
clientBuilder.setProxy(HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPortNum, "https"))
```

and everything works great.

How can I fix this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the proxy require user/password or some other auth mechanism?

Comment: No, it doesn't in my case.

Comment: Do you want to create an issue here https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues with a reproducible examples if it is possible?

Comment: Sure. I'll do it as soon as possible.

Comment: @VioletaGeorgieva I looked into your github issues, but couldn't find this. Was it solved somehow? I am facing a similar issue and cannot understand what to do.

Comment: @Purfakt unfortunately I didn't open an issue. I can't find a proxy server with ssl for reproduction this problem. If your server is available from the internet we can try to create a reproducible example.

Comment: @IV My server isn't available from internet. I eventually got the problem solved and it wasn't exactly related to your issue but more configuration at my customer.